# Import Data from Microsoft Outlook to Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter, outlook

Can anyone tell me how to link Microsoft Outlook with Microsoft Excel using Excel VBA in such a manner that the mail with specific subject will be filtered, then in that mail specific data will be imported to a particular cell of excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code I've used in the past. You'll need to update some things like the name of the sheet and Outlook folder. Please read through the code and try to figure out what it's doing.

```
Sub PullOutlookData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim lrow As Long 
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Complex") '<--- change to relevant worksheet
Set olItems = olNs.Folders("steven.walker@myemail.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Travel").Items '<---CHANGE TO RELEVANT FOLDER
rCount = 1

For Each olItem In olItems
    rCount = rCount + 1
    ws.Range("A" & rCount).Value = olItem.SenderName
    ws.Range("B" & rCount).Value = olItem.Subject
    ws.Range("C" & rCount).Value = olItem.Body
    ws.Range("D" & rCount).Value = olItem.ReceivedTime
Next olItem
ws.UsedRange.WrapText = False


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: But i think it will not work for real time system, like on my office outlook i receive approx. 250 mails/ hr, most of them are useless, therefore i want to filter the specific subject mails which are of my use and then import specifc data from it.

Comment: Consider setting up an Outlook rule that pushes the filter emails you are looking for into a specific folder and then use the above from Excel every so often based on the content in the subject. Alternatively, you should do some research for an Outlook macro that does something similar to the above, and attach it to a new mail event (I think Outlook has one) so it is triggered when a new mail is received. Do an if/case statement to only run the code on emails that match what you're looking for. Security restrictions stop me from Outlook VBA (i don't use it) so can't help further, sorry.

Comment: Here's an article on using Outlook rules. For what you need, rules will probably work better than VBA.

Comment: Thanks for help bro! I will try it today.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-messages-by-using-rules-80CC1F28-533D-4879-A8CC-EF83E9AF0495